# How can I prevent child window changing parent window behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I have a page with a link with opening attribute '_blank'. But when click the link and open a new window, there are scripts in the new window, like 'window.opener.location' which changes the parent window's behaviors. However, this is not I wanted. How can I prevent this happening.
Thanks.